# Creating two different domains on single machine

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, domain, windows

I have one DNS server installed on windows 2003 server in our private network.
I have configured one domain (xyz.com) on this same machine with all forward lookup and reverse lookup zone.
Now I want to create one more domain not subdomain on this same machine.
So I want to create pqr.com and not pqr.xyz.com.

Is it possible, if yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question if you're referring to an AD domain or a DNS forward lookup zone. Did you create an AD domain named xyz.com with a corresponding DNS zone and you now want to create a new AD domain named pqr.com?

Or is it that you want to create only a new DNS zone named pqr.com?

If it's the latter then just create a new forward lookup zone on your DNS server named pqr.com.

Comment: Not AD domain just DNS domain, I will try your solution.

Comment: OK then, simply create a new forward lookup zone on the server (at the root, not at your existing zone). Just right click the Forward Lookup Zones node and select "New Zone" and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Though I created new zone added some host for it and configured forwarder. And the hostnames in the domains are getting pinged. But I was trying to register one PC in the network to this domain, error comes up saying 'domain controller' pqr.com can't be contacted. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well the new zone isn't the DNS zone for your AD domain, it's just a standard forward lookup zone and as such no domain SRV records exist in this zone. What are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you're trying to create a new AD domain and join computers to it? Is that the case?

Comment: Oh, I got that after reading somethings about this issue. It seems I was treating new domain as new AD domain and not DNS domain, so it happened. But just having DNS domain can solve my problem. But what I really wanted to achieve is to have two different domains on same machine and register different PCs in same subnet say pc A to xyz domain and pc B to pqr domain. In that case I think I need to create two AD domains and not DNS domain. And I suppose creating two AD domain on single machine is not possible.?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You need to create a new AD domain. You can create a new one in the existing AD forest or you can create a new "standalone" domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You need to create a new zone on the server. After you do that you can create all of the necessary records like you did for the first zone.